# I couldn't understand how this code works

Tags: c++

This is my header file:

```
#pragma once

template <typename T>
T Sub(T a, T b)
{
   return a - b;
}
```

This is my sample reference C++ source file.

```
#include "NonrecursiveInorderTree.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T1, typename T2>
void ShowData(T1 a, T2 b)
{
  cout << a << "";
  cout << b << endl;

}


int main(void)
{
  ShowData(1, 2);
  ShowData(3, 2.5);

  return 0;
}
```

I'm studying templates and I could not understand how my code works with the header file.

I mean, Even though the header file has a subtract function, why this result is not subtraction like -1 or 0.5? Instead I get 12 and 32.5?
How can I write `sub(a, b)` to `cout`?

Comment: Let the statement inside the `ShowData` be `cout << Sub(a, b) << endl`.

Comment: But you don't use `Sub` anywhere? When creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please make sure it is *complete*. Also, what's with the `NonrecursiveInorderTree.h` header file? Is it where you have the `Sub` template?

Comment: It prints 12 and 32.5 because it does not print a space this line `cout << a << ""`. It prints 1 and 2, 3 and 2.5 without space between two numbers.

Comment: You have two template types in `ShowData()`, but only one in `Sub()`. Which type of the types in `ShowData()` would you like to use in `Sub()`?

Answer (score 0):

You have `Sub()` function implemented, but you didn't call it:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void ShowData(T1 a, T2 b)
{
    // It's better to explicitly use std prefix
    std::cout << Sub<int>(a, b) << std::endl;
}
```

BTW, the result would be:

```
-1
1
```

The second result is not 0.5. Because 2.5 will be convert to int(as specified when calling `Sub()`) automatically, the floating point part will be lost.

Comment: This doesn't meet the templatization of `ShowData`.

Answer (score -1):

Replace this:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void ShowData(T1 a, T2 b)
{
  cout << a << "";
  cout << b << endl;

}
```

With this

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void ShowData(T1 a, T2 b)
{
  cout << Sub<T1>(a,b)<<endl;


}
```

Assuming `"NonrecursiveInorderTree.h"` is the header file.

Answer (score -2):

`Sub` is not called because you don't call `Sub`. The computer is doing exactly what you told it to do.

If you want `ShowData` to print `a` minus `b` then write:

```
cout << Sub(a, b) << endl;
```

instead of:

```
cout << a << "";
cout << b << endl;
```

Comment: This doesn't meet the templatization of `ShowData`.

Comment: @パスカル What's your problem? It works for me in the first call, and not in the second call because it can't deduce `T`, but that's not the problem the question asks about.

Comment: Sub is a template. You are treating it as a function. You should make it a template with type T1

Comment: @パスカル You don't know about template argument deduction...?